# Laravel what's the right mode to output a server-side generated image?

Tags: php, laravel, image

I created a route with the purpose to track email opening

```
Route::get('/stats/{token}/pixel-email-read.png', 
           'StatController@trackEmailRead')
       ->name('stats.pixel-email-read');
```

I am using it in email building, as follows

```
<img src="{{ route('stats.pixel-email-read', [ 'token' => $order->token ] ) }}">
```

Actual code is generating a 1x1 transparent ping

```
public function trackEmailRead(Request $request, string $token)
    {
        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        echo base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8Xw8AAoMBgDTD2qgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    }
```

It works in email, but, it don't work in browser.

If I open browser I got this

[image]

I'd like to see browser opening my link as an image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just fyi, i see no point in using echo in a Laravel application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I marked as best answer the one by Kevin, but I add my own question only for future alternative ideas.

I served a file instead of echoing, like suggested by comment of mrhn

```
public function trackEmailRead(Request $request, string $token)
{
    $order = Order::where(['token' => $token])->first();
    if ($order && !$order->email_read_at) {
        $order->update([
            'email_read_at' => now()
        ]);
    }
    return response()->file(public_path() . '/images/pixel.png');
}
```

> YES, I Know !! You're thinking I could do a direct update using 'email_read_at' in a whereNull condition, but ... in the real code, between query and if, there is some other business logic ...

Answer (score 3):

Provided the routes going to the image and whatnot are correct, use the `response()` object helper and load the base64 image, and finally attach the content type.

Here's the idea:

```
public function trackEmailRead(Request $request, string $token)
{
    $base64_img = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP8Xw8AAoMBgDTD2qgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=');
    
    return response($base64_img)->header('Content-type', 'image/png');
}
```